# How to alert user about ram hard drive or battery in iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am able to get ram, hard disk and battery info and would like to inform users when free hdd, ram or battery is (let's say) less than 20% even if my app is not running.. Is it possible? Thanks..

Comment: No you cannot run program when the application is running in background/ or not running

Comment: if its in the background, i can use applicationDidEnterBackground method but that's not what I want..

Comment: i have seen an app that monitors network activities.. it even informs when a certain usage limit has been reached.. how does it do it then?

Comment: which application you have seen?? `applicationDidEnterBackground ` calls only once if the application is going to background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. You *might* be able to shoehorn in to the significant location change API, which provides notification when the device changes cell towers, but this will really only work if the user moves on a regular basis (and Apple may well reject your app because you're not actually interested in the user's location).

There may be apps that monitor a network *account* and send a push notification message when certain thresholds are met, but all the polling and logic for this will occur on a centralised server (e.g. at your ISP) and not on the device. Such app(s) may well provide additional info *while they're running*—it would be possible, I think, to do this in a manner that appears to the user as though the app is running in the background, when in fact it isn't.

(If you only want this for yourself—i.e. you're a developer running your own code on your own device, and don't need to comply with the App Store guidelines—then you may also be able to use the VoIP background task type. This will get you the heartbeat-style polling you're after, but you **will not** get in to the App Store using the VoIP background task type for non-VoIP things—just ask the people who made Sparrow.)